# Convert string array to array of array in python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have input like this

```
logs = ['88 99 200','88 99 300','99 32 100','12 12 15']
```

How to convert it into an array of array in Python
like this?

```
logs = [[88 99 200],[88 99 300],[99 32 100],[12 12 15]]
```

Comment: Please first suggest what you have tried, where you got stuck and correct your output (commas?).

Comment: You have a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-list) here. An [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) is a different thing in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.split` with `map` :

```py
list(map(str.split, logs))


Out[36]:
[['88', '99', '200'],
 ['88', '99', '300'],
 ['99', '32', '100'],
 ['12', '12', '15']]
```

If you want to convert each item to `int`:

```py
list(map(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x], map(str.split, logs)))


Out[37]: [[88, 99, 200], [88, 99, 300], [99, 32, 100], [12, 12, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to convert.

```
logs = ['88 99 200','88 99 300','99 32 100','12 12 15']
logs = [[i] for i in logs]
```

other way is

```
logs2 = []
for i in logs:
    logs2.append([i])
```